# DC from audio jack

Tags: wav

I would like to try to get a DC output from the audiojack on my phone. My first thought is that I could get a full wave rectifier circuit and convert the signal (AC like) to DC. My second thought was to try to create a .wav file that had a flat signal. Could this work? Could I somehow create a flat signal that kept one speaker line high relative to the ground line?

I kind of want to test this and thought that if I just knew what the headers and things for a .wav were then I can just copy and paste some numbers into it and see what it happens to sound like.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick experiment you could use Audacity with some filter to generate a signal with a DC offset.

A cheap builtin audio chip is likely to have some sort of low pass filter in its amp to avoid smoking itself though. That's why it might be a good idea, as you mentioned, to test this cheaply.